# Control for regression to the mean effects when comparing propensity score matched observations?

Tags: ancova, propensity-scores, regression-to-the-mean

I'm working on a project where I'm comparing the % change in total annual health care expenditures among patients who did or did not participate in a cost reduction intervention program.

We're considering a standard propensity score matching methodology to assign members to one of *k* strata and then conducting paired t-tests between treatment and control groups in each strata to assess if the intervention program has significantly reduced health care expenditures.

My question: Should I control for regression to the mean effects within each of the *k* strata, for example by using ANCOVA? Or will the propensity score matching naturally cancel out any regression to the mean effects?

Comment: As an aside what is the value of $k$?  Many analysts choose a value that is too low and results in residual confounding.  I would guess that $k=20$ is needed in many situations, hence we often look to regression adjustment (using a spline in the logit propensity score or using covariates directly)  because of better handling of residual confounding.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - We haven't chosen the value of *k* yet. We have ~7,000 subjects and probably about 40 separate demographic and behavioral/medical diagnosis variables. So with *k* = 20 should propensity score matching control for regression to the mean effects (in addition to confounding issues)?

Comment: Matching will result in discarding observations and is not advised.  Not sure about regression to the mean in this context.  Needs more explanation.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - My primary concern is after I've assigned members with similar propensity scores to each of the *k* strata, in at least some strata there will be members in the treatment group who had extremely low (or high) baseline (pre-intervention) health care expenses and/or members in the control group who had extremely high (or low) expenses, and that the regression to the mean effect will be a significant component of the % change in costs we're attempting to measure. Actually, my worries may be unfounded - a well-designed PSM should control for this, right?

Comment: I may be missing the point but I think you need to be sure to adjust for the baseline value as a separate covariate, and if you lack sample size enough to need propensity adjustment for confounding, use a method that does not have residual confounding, such as the propensity covariate adjustment I suggested, once you determine propensity overlap regions to condition the analysis on.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - Thanks - after some thought we're reconsidering the propensity score analysis and may indeed go with a regression containing the baseline health care expenditures (actually the z-score) as a covariate in order to capture the regression to the mean effect as you've suggested.

Comment: I don't think that z-scores have much meaning here, and make a lot of assumptions.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - I thought the z-score covariate would be a convenient way to measure the distance of the baseline cost from the overall baseline average. I could also use (baseline cost - baseline average) as the covariate. Not a good idea?

Comment: I would try to state the model in terms of the raw data, and without calculating any differences.